# JQuery find most recent date from list

Tags: jquery

I have a list of dates and I'd like to grab the most recent one, and display it in the H2 (specifically the span.lastupdated tag).

```
<h2>Specials (Updated <span class="lastUpdated"></span>)</h2>

<ul class="items">
<li>June 1, 2017</li>
<li>August 1, 2017</li>
<li>September 27, 2017</li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this with jQUery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make them into date objects, you can directly compare them with `<`:

```js
var date = new Date('Jan 1 1980');
var dateString = '';
$('.items li').each(function(num, elem) {
  var thisDate = new Date($(elem).text());
  if (thisDate > date) {
    date = thisDate;
    dateString = $(elem).text();
  }
});
$('.lastUpdated').text(dateString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Specials (Updated <span class="lastUpdated"></span>)</h2>

<ul class="items">
<li>June 1, 2017</li>
<li>August 1, 2017</li>
<li>September 27, 2017</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var listDates = [];
        $('.items li').each(function (i) {
            var listDateValue = $(this).text();
            listDates.push(listDateValue);
        });
        var formattedDates = listDates.map(function(x) { return new Date(x); }) //contains the list of dates available within each item in your ul element.
        var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,formattedDates));
        $(".lastUpdated").html(maxDate);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in one loop:

```
var mostRecent = null;
var position = null;
var items = $('.items').children();

items.each(function(index, element) {
    var temp = new Date($(element).text());
    if (!mostRecent || temp > mostRecent) {
        mostRecent = temp;
        position = index;
    }
});
if (position != null)
    $('span.lastUpdated').text($(items[position]).text());
```